# Copy selected checkboxes into another div

Tags: javascript, html

http://jsfiddle.net/pxzt8kvp/

This code is for a form where the user can select various things and have a display of their current selection. I would like it to display the actual element instead of the element's text, as eventually it will be an image thumbnail.

I found code similar to what I need, although it only puts the text values into another div. I need the actual input elements, not just the plain text. I've tried removing the .text() from the javasript but that doesn't copy anything to the div.

HTML:

```
<div id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_divServices" style="width:450px; height:250px; overflow-y:scroll;">
    <input id="1" type="checkbox" name="1"/><label for="1"><div id="thing">One</div></label>
    <input id="2" type="checkbox" name="2"/><label for="2"><div id="thing">Two</div></label>
    <input id="3" type="checkbox" name="3"/><label for="3"><div id="thing">Three</div></label>
    <input id="4" type="checkbox" name="4"/><label for="4"><div id="thing">Four</div></label>
</div>
<div id="selectedServices">
    <p>Result:<div id="myDiv"></div></p>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
$(function() {
  $(":checkbox").change(function() {
    var arr = $(":checkbox:checked").map(function() { return $(this).next().text(); }).get();
    $("#myDiv").text(arr.join(', '));
  });
});

function ToggleBGColour(item) {
    var td = $(item).parent();      
    if (td.is('.rowSelected'))      
        td.removeClass("rowSelected");      
    else        
        td.addClass("rowSelected");     
}
```

Comment: `I need the actual input elements` I'm not sure I actually understand what you're wanting here. Could you maybe elaborate? Do you want to retrieve the entire element itself? If so, `cloneNode()` or jQuery's `.clone()` may be useful, but they do have caveats.

Comment: instead of text() use html(), both for getting and setting

Comment: Thanks Drew, yes I meant the entire element.

Comment: I'll try both suggestions, thank you.

Comment: Thanks Roozbeh, html() did the trick! I can't mark this as solved though.

Comment: Your welcome. I posted my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

instead of text() use html(), both for getting and setting

http://jsfiddle.net/pxzt8kvp/1/

```
$(function() {
  $(":checkbox").change(function() {
    var arr = $(":checkbox:checked").map(function() { return $(this).next().html(); }).get();
    $("#myDiv").html(arr.join(', '));
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

While you've already accepted an answer, I'd like to suggest the following approaches instead, the first using jQuery:

```
// caching the element (of id='myDiv') in which
// the output should be displayed:
var results = $('#myDiv'),

// because we'll be using this collection at least twice,
// the first to bind the event-handlers and the second
// to find the checked elements, we cache it here to
// reduce DOM queries:
    checks = $('#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_divServices input[type=checkbox]');

// binding the anonymous function of the on() method
// as the event-handler of the 'change' event:
checks.on('change', function() {

  // caching the checked check-box <input> elements
  // and their next-sibling (the associated <label>):
  var clones = checks
    // filtering the cached list of check-box <input>
    // elements to retain only those that are checked:
    .filter(':checked')
    // finding the next-sibling element
    .next()
    // adding back the previous collection, that of the
    // checked check-box elements:
    .addBack()
    // cloning those elements
    .clone()
    // iterating over each element of the collection:
    .each(function() {
      // if the element has an id, and has a type and that
      // type is exactly equal to 'checkbox':
      if (this.id && this.type && this.type === 'checkbox') {
        // we remove the id attribute (a duplicate id
        // renders the document invalid); we leave the
        // 'for' attribute of the <label> alone because
        // that way it still triggers the 'change' event
        // of the cloned/'original' checkbox, which maintains
        // desired functionality:
        this.removeAttribute('id');
      }
    });

  // here we remove the current/previously-set contents
  // of the results element (cached above):
  results.empty()
    // and append the just-found cloned elements:
    .append(clones);
});
```

```js
var results = $('#myDiv'),
  checks = $('#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_divServices input[type=checkbox]');

checks.on('change', function() {
  var clones = checks.filter(':checked').next().addBack().clone().each(function() {
    if (this.id && this.type && this.type === 'checkbox') {
      this.removeAttribute('id');
    }
  });
  results.empty().append(clones);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_divServices" style="width:450px; height:250px; overflow-y:scroll;">
  <input id="1" type="checkbox" name="1" />
  <label for="1">
    <div id="thing">One</div>
  </label>
  <input id="2" type="checkbox" name="2" />
  <label for="2">
    <div id="thing">Two</div>
  </label>
  <input id="3" type="checkbox" name="3" />
  <label for="3">
    <div id="thing">Three</div>
  </label>
  <input id="4" type="checkbox" name="4" />
  <label for="4">
    <div id="thing">Four</div>
  </label>
</div>
<div id="selectedServices">
  <p>Result:<span id="myDiv"></span>
  </p>
</div>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/b33c571n/).

With plain JavaScript, however, the above could be re-written as:

```
// caching the repeatedly accessed elements for
// efficiency:
var results = document.getElementById('myDiv'),
  checks = document.querySelectorAll('#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_divServices input[type=checkbox]'),

// using Array.from() to turn the array-like NodeList 
// returned by document.querySelectorAll into an array:
  checksArray = Array.from(checks);

// iterating over that array of check-boxes:
checksArray.forEach(function(check) {
  // the first, and here only, argument ('check')
  // is the current array-element of the array
  // over which we're iterating.

  // here we add an event-listener for the 'change'
  // event, which will trigger the anonymous function:
  check.addEventListener('change', function() {

    // filtering the checksArray array of check-boxes,
    // retaining only those that are checked; here we
    // use an Arrow function which uses the named
    // function parameter ('el'), which is the first
    // parameter of the Array.prototype.filter() method
    // (as above the first parameter is the array-element
    // of the array over which we're iterating). Here if
    // the return value of 'el.checked' is true the element
    // is retained, otherwise it's discarded:
    var checked = checksArray.filter(el => el.checked),

    // an empty array-literal for use subsequently:
      clones = [],

    // a document fragment to allow all elements to be
    // appended in one call, rather than appending multiple
    // times causing the document to be drawn and re-drawn:
      frag = document.createDocumentFragment();

    // iterating over the array of checked check-boxes:
    checked.forEach(function(el) {

      // pushing the cloned checkbox, and its next sibling
      // the <label>, into the initialised array:
      clones.push(el.cloneNode(), el.nextElementSibling.cloneNode(true));
    });

    // using Array.prototype.map() to return a new array
    // of elements, after removing the 'id' from the
    // elements with an id and a type and that type is
    // exactly equal to 'checkbox'
    // (Array.prototype.forEach() could be used instead,
    // but it's slightly easier using map()):
    clones.map(function(el) {
      if (el.id && el.type && el.type === 'checkbox') {
        el.removeAttribute('id');
      }
      return el;

    // iterating over the array returned by map()
    // and appending the elements ('el') to the
    // created document.fragment:
    }).forEach(el => frag.appendChild(el));

    // emptying the results element, using a while
    // loop; while the element has a firstChild we
    // remove that firstChild:
    while (results.firstChild) {
      results.removeChild(results.firstChild);
    }

    // appending the document fragment to the
    // results element:
    results.appendChild(frag);
  });
});
```

```js
var results = document.getElementById('myDiv'),
  checks = document.querySelectorAll('#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_divServices input[type=checkbox]'),
  checksArray = Array.from(checks);

checksArray.forEach(function(check) {
  check.addEventListener('change', function() {
    var checked = checksArray.filter(el => el.checked),
      clones = [],
      frag = document.createDocumentFragment();

    checked.forEach(function(el) {
      clones.push(el.cloneNode(), el.nextElementSibling.cloneNode(true));
    });

    clones.map(function(el) {
      if (el.id && el.type && el.type === 'checkbox') {
        el.removeAttribute('id');
      }
      return el;
    }).forEach(el => frag.appendChild(el));
    while (results.firstChild) {
      results.removeChild(results.firstChild);
    }
    results.appendChild(frag);
  });
});
```

```html
<div id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_divServices" style="width:450px; height:250px; overflow-y:scroll;">
  <input id="1" type="checkbox" name="1" />
  <label for="1">
    <div id="thing">One</div>
  </label>
  <input id="2" type="checkbox" name="2" />
  <label for="2">
    <div id="thing">Two</div>
  </label>
  <input id="3" type="checkbox" name="3" />
  <label for="3">
    <div id="thing">Three</div>
  </label>
  <input id="4" type="checkbox" name="4" />
  <label for="4">
    <div id="thing">Four</div>
  </label>
</div>
<div id="selectedServices">
  <p>Result:<span id="myDiv"></span>
  </p>
</div>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/b33c571n/2/).

Note that, in the above demos, I've amended your HTML slightly to exchange the:

```
<div id="selectedServices">
  <p>Result:<div id="myDiv"></div></p>
</div>
```

With:

```
<div id="selectedServices">
  <p>Result:<span id="myDiv"></span></p>
</div>
```

This is purely because a `<div>` element cannot be contained within a `<p>` element. It may have been easier, however, to simply close the `<p>` element prior to the `<div>` element's opening tag. However, that's your call depending on your use-case.

---

Problems with other, currently existing, answers, or: *why I posted* this *answer to a question with an already-accepted answer*:

1. [Roozbeh hz's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34744861/82548):

   - You end up with at least two elements in the page sharing an `id`, which immediately renders your HTML invalid; and will also cause problems with JavaScript/jQuery should you need to act on the duplicate elements.
   - If your statement "*I need the actual input elements*" is true, then neither your own code nor Roozbeh's addresses that need, and duplicates only the text-content of the `<label>`. I don't know if this *is* a problem, but either way it indicates you should clarify your questions to be definite. However, I took that statement literally and preserved both the `<input>` elements and the `<label>` elements to be copied to the 'output' element.
2. [dajo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34744769/82548) offers no explanation of the code supplied, so while it may – or may not – work it's hard for anyone to learn anything from that answer.
3. [John C.'s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34744912/82548) is briefly explained and has undocumented code, offering only a jQuery solution (as do all current answers at the point of writing this answer) to what may be a problem common enough to merit a plain JavaScript answer; and also uses the slightly inefficient `:checkbox` selector<sup>see references</sup> which has to be implemented in jQuery/Sizzle, rather than the `input[type=checkbox]` selector which can be passed to the native `document.querySelectorAll()`<sup>see references</sup> method and is marginally faster and more efficient; as the jQuery API itself notes:

> Because `:checkbox` is a jQuery extension and not part of the CSS specification, queries using `:checkbox` cannot take advantage of the performance boost provided by the native DOM `querySelectorAll()` method. For better performance in modern browsers, use `[type="checkbox"]` instead.

It's worth acknowledging, though, that this is a micro-optimisation and almost entirely a personal preference.

4. [Venugopal's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34744882/82548) is, again, briefly explained, though his code is also undocumented to explain how the solution is implemented.

References:

- JavaScript:

  - [`Array.from()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from).
  - [`Array.prototype.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).
  - [`Array.prototype.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).
  - [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).
  - [`Array.prototype.push()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push).
  - [Arrow (`node => node.doSomething()`) functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).
  - [`document.createDocumentFragment()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createDocumentFragment).
  - [`document.getElementById()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById).
  - [`document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll).
  - [`Element.removeAttribute()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/removeAttribute).
  - [`EventTarget.addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener).
  - [`Node.appendChild()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild).
  - [`Node.cloneNode()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/cloneNode).
  - [`Node.removeChild()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/removeChild).
  - [`while () {...}` loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/while).
- jQuery:

  - [`:checkbox` selector](http://api.jquery.com/checkbox-selector/).
  - [`addBack()`](http://api.jquery.com/addBack/).
  - [`append()`](http://api.jquery.com/append/).
  - [`clone()`](http://api.jquery.com/clone/).
  - [`each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/).
  - [`empty()`](http://api.jquery.com/empty/).
  - [`filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/).
  - [`next()`](http://api.jquery.com/next/).
  - [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

Comment: +1, great answer!  Though in my defense of the use `:checkbox` I was leaving the OP's original code mostly unchanged and only making the changes required to meet the goal.  Re-reading the question though it seems the quoted code is simply pulled from the web so the idea of doing a full re-write of the function (with documentation) seems like a very good idea from a teaching standpoint.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 $(function() {
  $(":checkbox").change(function() {
    var arr = $(":checkbox:checked").map(function() { return $(this).attr('id'); }).get();
    $("#myDiv").text(arr.join(', '));
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

clone the `label` and add to target div `#myDiv`

```
$(function() {
    $(":checkbox").change(function() {
        var arr = $(":checkbox:checked").map(function() {
            return $(this).next();
        }).get();
        $("#myDiv").html('');
        arr.forEach(function(a) {
            $("#myDiv").append($(a).clone());
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

First instead of returning a string from your map function return a clone of the checked `input` and it's following `label`.  Then you just need to append your array of elements to your `div`.  See below (I've left the code mostly unchanged from what you provided, only making the changes necessary to achieve your goal) -

```js
$(function() {
    $(":checkbox").change(function() {
      // Clear the contents of #myDiv
      $("#myDiv").empty();
      var arr = $(":checkbox:checked").map(function() {
        // This will select the current element, add the following
        // item to the selection and return cloned versions of the 
        // selection
        return $(this).add($(this).next()).clone();
      }).get();
      // Add the items to #myDiv
      $("#myDiv").append(arr);
    });
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_divServices" style="width:450px; height:250px; overflow-y:scroll;">
  <input id="1" type="checkbox" name="1" />
  <label for="1">
    <div id="thing">One</div>
  </label>
  <input id="2" type="checkbox" name="2" />
  <label for="2">
    <div id="thing">Two</div>
  </label>
  <input id="3" type="checkbox" name="3" />
  <label for="3">
    <div id="thing">Three</div>
  </label>
  <input id="4" type="checkbox" name="4" />
  <label for="4">
    <div id="thing">Four</div>
  </label>
</div>
<div id="selectedServices">
  Result:
  <div id="myDiv"></div>
</div>
```